# Unable to start uiautomatorviewer

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-uiautomator

I have :

- Android SDK Tools, Revision 22
- Android SDK Platform, API 18

I go to `<android-sdk>/tools/` , I see there is one file named "`uiautomatorviewer`",

I execute command `uiautomatorviewer` from terminal under the above path, however I got the following message:

```
uiautomatorviewer: command not found
```

why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because your `tools/` directory is not in your `PATH`. Either use `./uiautomatorviewer` or add `tools/` (and probably `platform-tools/` to your `PATH`. Note that this has nothing to do with programming and everything to do with your *nix-style OS (Linux, OS X, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I am using MacBook Pro

Comment: This answer is outdated (although it was current when posted). Still, this same location is still used in google's official instructions here: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing . @CommonsWare do you know what is the procedure to alter this documentation?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: "do you know what is the procedure to alter this documentation?" -- [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues), then pray that Google pays attention to it.

Comment: Now the question is how do I open an issue about their issue creation form not working (component dropdown does not load anything in Chrome for Linux) :) At least my prayers are spared

Answer (score 64):

Please note that `uiautomatorviewer` executable has been moved in [SDK Tools Revision 25.3.0](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017) update (Feb 2017) to new location under `<android-sdk>\tools\bin`

Answer (score 3):

Just follow these steps,

Open `command prompt`,Go to your `bin` folder inside `tools` folder of sdk location.

*Example:* `C:\android-sdk\android-sdk\tools\bin`.

Then in **`cmd`** type `uiautomatorviewer` and hit enter. It would immedialy open UI Automator Viewer.

```
C:\android-sdk\android-sdk\tools\bin>uiautomatorviewer
```

Refer screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thnx bro. You saved me a few hours of time

Comment: I Get the following error, and I don't understand what I am doing wrong (Bash on Ubuntu):
-Djava.ext.dirs=<android-sdk>/tools/lib/x86_64:<android-sdk>/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to **tools** folder, then launch terminal, launch monitor(Android Device Monitor) using ./monitor command.

ADM will get launched, left side of the window you may find [image: uiautomatorviewer].

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to find it still on a fresh Android SDK download: this has been removed from the standard tools in API level 27. To install it, [uncheck **"Hide Obsolete Packages"** and select **"Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)" v 26.1.1**.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040516/253468) or use `sdkmanager --install tools`.

[image]

and after this point, see other answers here.

*See the [Deprecation notice for more info](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools), there's no explicit mention of `uiautomatorviewer` removal, but after [9 major releases](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/cmdline-tools) ([if you don't see 9+ yet, see here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266618722)) of [Command Line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-line-tools-only) there's no sign of it in the `cmdline-tools/latest` folder.*

Comment: I have SDK 33 installed and uiautomatorviewer is still there under tools/bin (OSX)

Comment: @m0skit0 _SDK Platform / Android API 34_ (`platforms` & `sources`), _Android SDK Build-Tools 34 / 34.0.0_ (`build-tools`), _Android Platform SDK Tools 34.0.4_ (`platform-tools`), _Android SDK Command-line Tools 12.0.0_ (`cmdline-tools`) are all different; and can be installed side-by-side for many versions, see the (folders). The `tools` folder only exists if the _Android SDK Tools_ is installed which has only one version now. I would be very surprised if you have the `tools` folder but don't have _Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)_ ticked. (You need to uncheck "Hide Obsolete Packages" to verify.)

Comment: No obsolete package installed whatsoever.

Comment: To install the legacy/obsolete SDK tools with `sdkmanger`, run `sdkmanager --install 'tools'`

Answer (score 1):

First, follow this tutorial to add `ANDROID_HOME` and `Path` variables.

[Setup Android Environment Variables](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/setup-android-environment-variables/)

Then, add this variable as variables in the tutorial.

```
Variable name: JAVA_HOME
Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
```

Now you can run `uiautomatorviewer` in
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`.

Comment: thanks for this it was realy useful since all answer which i checked was outdated

Answer (score 0):

It's path issue only so don't worry
just put this path "%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin" in your system path.
Now you can run uiautomatorviewer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).