# Android Studio not letting me change SDK Location

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I open up Android Studio. Then I open up SDK manager. I have the most up to date version but, I need Android 6.0 for my SDK platform. It doesn't even let me click anything.

In this image you can see the text and check boxes are discolored. I can't click anything inside the SDK Platform, or even the the Tools and update sites. I can't check the box "Show Package Details". You can see a screenshot bellow.

[image]

I have installed and changed it sucessfully on another laptop of mine, but I can't get it to work here.

Comment: That is the thing, I can't install the packages in while in my SDK manager

Comment: use the stand alone sdk manger

Comment: I installed sdk manager with Android Studio. Do I have to install the stand alone sdk manager, if so can you provide a link? If i use the stand alone will i have to change SDK location?

Comment: No, go the the path of sdk and open sdk manger.exe as admin

Comment: and you may also want to try to run Android studio itself as Admin, maybe that what causes it to be disabled !

Comment: **check up this answer: **
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697515/11239018)

Comment: **Check This ANSWER: ** [Use Proxy to Fix Android Studio SDK Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697515/11239018)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sdk path has problem.The sdk path you provided has whitespace.Remove that and reset path again.Rename your path to remove whitespace.set something like "C:\Users\Tarique_Shams\AppData\Local\Android\sdk".

Comment: Is there an easier way to doing it than uninstalling and reinstalling in a different directory?

Comment: Just rename your path.Rename your folder from Tarique Shams to Tarique_Shams or TariqueShams. thats it.

Comment: I thought I couldn't changer a User Account folder?

Comment: What do you mean by this?i can't understand.

Comment: I don't have a rename option when I right-click the folder. I was doing some reading and found this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/rename-user-account-folder-in-windows-10-preview/88033eca-6b32-47c5-90ac-a5e7af17d094

Comment: I will try to fix this my reinstalling and setting up in a different directory.

Comment: it means you are not the admin of the system then ask admin to rename this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Command Prompt
2. Switch to users directory - `cd c:\users`
3. Type `dir /x` and hit `Enter`
4. See the short name for your user directory "Tarique Shams"

Example of where you'll see it (highlighted in yellow are the short names for directories with white spaces in the name):

[image]

5. For your directory "Tarique Shams" it should be `TARIQU~1` (But, cross check with the `dir /x` command)
6. Replace "Tarique Shams" in the path with `TARIQU~1`
7. Save! You are good to go now.

In short: Your path should be something like this:

**C:\Users\TARIQU~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**

Comment: this is what i see:

Comment: did you put `/x` after `dir`

Comment: second last column (highlighted in yellow above) will show you the short name. You can just use the path I've given at the end of the answer.

Comment: I see, but when I go and try to change it, it reverts it back or doesn't change Tarique Shams to TARIQU~1

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had a white space in my SDK location. To solver it you can change folder name as DKThakur mentioned. In my case I couldn't because it was a User Account. I then tried solving it by using the short name as AndroidMechanic posted. I ran into some complications and just ended up reinstalling Android Studio and the SDK completely after deleting it completely from my computer including and local data. I installed it in another folder with no white spaces. Both DKThakur and AndroidMechanic posted solutions that work, but this is how I did it.

Here is a link to another post of how to completely develet android studio and sdk from your machine:
[How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10) .