# Android sdk is missing, out of date or corrupted (SDK tools directory is missing)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed android studio 3.0.1 in new PC.
when i open android studio, a message say :[image]

also when i want to download sdk it shows like this  :[image]

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789556/android-studio-sdk-tools-directory-is-missing

Comment: Not helpful :\ @sasikumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just download the latest api (API 27) and your desired android version.
[image]

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: click on the box near the android API 27, and the box near your android version. and then press ok, and android studio will start the download.

Comment: @StevenSugatov, those boxes are not enabled unless you can provide studio with an SDK to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

if you already have a sdk installed then give it's path in the box followed by android sdk location .
otherwise use this link 
https://developer.android.com/sdk/download.html

Comment: i didn't find the sdk tools

Comment: then use the link to download

Comment: after downloading give the path in box  followed by android sdk location

Comment: where i'll find it ?

Comment: The issue is that URL redirects to the studio page.  Obviously the OP already has the studio.  They must have moved the SDK.  Or they want the studio to manage sdk installations, but the program is easily soft locked out of having an SDK and there seems to be no way forward in the program and the resource on the net has been redirected.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem, use administrator privileges to open the Android studio is solved

Answer (score 0):

Buddy if you have downloaded sdk then provide path for sdk folder other wise download latest sdk and give path in your android studio for that:

Go to settings>appearance and behavior>android sdk>

Then in android sdk location click on edit.
There you have to provide path for downloaded sdk.

Comment: What if you have never installed the SDK?  The current url for the SDK just redirects to studio.  If it's so confident that the SDK is already installed so it refuses to install it, then why can't it automatically select the directory with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download android studio :-

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

How to update and setup :-

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your url redirects away from the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Click edit to provide the path of where u want to store the sdk in 
And then the checkboxes in the list will enable 
If not then download the sdk from the Android link separately and provide the path after extracting the sdk

As for downloading apis we can download it via sdk manager in the sdk zip or from the Android studio

Answer (score 0):

just delete all you did and get new android studio setup from link below :
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

it will install sdk-tools together.

Comment: can you tell in brief what exactly problem you are facing, which operating system you have. i have tested it in windows os, and it works fine. android studio setup asks for installing required components on first time, you can later install whatever you need to install as an extra.