# Error: "SDK emulator directory is missing" in Android Studio on Linux

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-2.3, manjaro

I'm trying to install android studio on `linux manjaro` but it shows me following error:

> SDK emulator directory is missing

How i can to fix it?

The error mesage:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Did you use a proxy? If so see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541869/3559908)

Comment: I always forget about my proxy. This comment saved my life. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry for my bad English.
i had this problem in windows 10, but may be my solution works for you.
i search about this problem for 3 days! and found out this issue occurs because of:

1. You are using bad VPN:
   for checking this run android studio and manually **TYPE** (in next item you will know why i am telling this) file address being download in browser. if you can download it, your connection has no problem.
   for example https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
   [Android studio download progress image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wImHh.png)
2. Your regional format is not to set English:
   as you can see in previous image, link contains a number (...addons_list-**2**) but because of regional format it not shown in English format and so it can not be downloaded. i used fiddler to recognize this; in fiddler link contained a "**?**" instead of "**2**"; so just change you regional format

Comment: It seems that you have given the reason but not the solution. Does your 'regional format' mean system setting or software setting?

Comment: I mean system setting

Comment: Thank you! This is excactly what I wanted

Comment: Weird! Changing the regional format setting works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks :) , it work for me , I'd changed format to : English(United States)

Answer (score 0):

I had gone through this problem,

1. First you have to go to the network icon and then right click on it and select open nitwork and internet sitting.
2. Then click on the change adapter option .
3. Then choose the wifi network, right-click on it, and then click on disable.
4. Then close Android Studio and go back to activate the mode that we made disable by pressing enable.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I was using a wrong proxy.

1. disable internet
2. open android studio
3. it would be a pop up for "setup proxy"
4. choose "no proxy"
5. enable internet
6. start android studio

Answer (score -1):

I met this problem this morning.

Because I did not drop Android Studio into Application directory, It disappear after it be drop into `/Users/{user name}/Applications` directory, you can drop it in `/Applications` or Launchpad, etc.

or, you can check SDK directory if exist, try to manual create `emulator` directory, but I think it not best way to try, because we should find the root cause (like access right, etc).

Good luck, hope you fix it already.