# Android Emulator Directory is Missing

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have recently come up with coding in dart and using flutter ...
after longtime spending for setting up SDK and stuffs for dart and flutter the only thing I need is an android studio set up and running SDK to it.
I'm actually running on Kali Linux and when I open an android studio I give it the directory file of the Android SDK but it says the folder is empty and there is no SDK (Sth like that ...). But I have downloaded the SDK recently... By the way when i click on next it warns me that the android emulator directory is missing!

Do the emulator or SDK needs a kind of root access !?
is there any way to connect the android SDK to vscode instead of an android studio?
Do android emulator only work on Ubuntu and no response for Debian based ?!

Comment: did you set  path to you android sdk folder?

Comment: Please use following link: <br/>
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67554080/15939622)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download the SDK separately android studio will automatically install it, and you can even choose with version of the SDK you want.

If you haven't gotten that option when installing. Reinstall it form the website!
Not some stupid PPA or app market https://developer.android.com/studio