# What is the solution for SDK emulator directory is missing?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Despite all the solutions I saw on the site, unfortunately my problem was not solved, I almost despair

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6MnO.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789556/android-studio-sdk-tools-directory-is-missing

Answer (score 1):

I can see "مشمس" word in your image that it means "Sunny"; so you are not using english regional format.
Your problem is probably because of your system regional format.
just set it to "English"
You can see detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67554080

Answer (score 0):

Emulator is part of andorid-sdk-tools.

Emulator help to make virtual device, you can dowload it later in android studio.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant

Comment: Try to reinstall SDK tools.

Comment: I can't find the complete SDK file online, please help

Comment: If you don't need virtual device just ignore it. Else remove installed SDK and download newone "https://www.techspot.com/amp/downloads/5425-android-sdk.html" and install it.