# Android Studio licences have not been accepted error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I installed latest Android studio on Arch Linux PC using instructions mentioned on [official website](https://developer.android.com/studio/install).
But I am not able to build my program, as this error is showing :

```
Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted. build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
```

I tried to follow some answers on SO and elsewhere that say to execute `sdkmanager --licenses` and accept the licences. But I'm not able to locate it. I tried searching for it in `/opt/android_studio/bin/` where I had installed it and in `/home/user/Android/Sdk/` but could'nt find it.

Comment: You should be able to find `sdkmanager` in `/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/bin`.

Comment: There is no tools folder

Comment: In that case maybe look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789556/android-studio-sdk-tools-directory-is-missing  Or you can reinstall the whole Android Studio as David Enoma suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching through the internet and try to apply various solutions, I found out that below the warning `Failed to install the following Android SDK packages ...` there was a link to download the `Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2` which I had'nt noticed before, on clicking on it I was presented with the licence agreement which after I accepted, the build tools were downloaded and the error went way and the app started building fine.

Thank you all for your help.