# Android developer tools not found even after installing Android studio

Tags: android, rust-cargo, android-sdk-tools

I'm using Zorin OS (ubuntu)
When Trying to run cargo mobile2 I get following errors: Failed to open SDK Tools
And Yes I can confirm there is **no Tools folder** in Android Home, but there is build-tools.
[image: android-folder]

```bash
 ajinkya@Shivoham  ~/Projects/2048-mobile   master  cargo mobile doctor

[✔] cargo-mobile v0.11.0
    • Contains commits up to "Publish New Versions (#286)\n"
    • Installed at "~/.cargo/.cargo-mobile2"
    • Zorin OS v17.1
    • rustc v1.77.0 (aedd173a2 2024-3-17)

[!] Android developer tools
    ✗ Failed to get SDK version: Failed to open "/home/ajinkya/Android/Sdk/tools/source.properties":
      No such file or directory (os error 2)
    • NDK v26.2.11394342 installed at "~/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.2.11394342/"

[✔] Connected devices
    • No connected devices were found
```

exported variables:

```bash
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME="~/.android/avd"
export NDK_HOME="$ANDROID_HOME/ndk/26.2.11394342/"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/34.0.0/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/
```

[image: android studio]

Comment: found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040516/942317

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your PATH contains the Android/Sdk/tools entry as well.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/
```

btw. what the reason for your "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"? It's redundant to ANDROID_HOME which is the proper one.

Comment: my Android folder doesnt have have tools at above path.

Comment: the tools folder contains the emulator, please check there is your emulator file located.